# Acquiring Stanford Dependencies representation from annotated document (Java)

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to retrieve the Stanford Dependencies representation of a sentence. Something like this:

```
nsubj(makes-8, Bell-1)
nsubj(distributes-10, Bell-1)
vmod(Bell-1, based-3)
```

I am using a coreNLP pipeline with the ddeparse annotator. The following code produces output in a similar, but not as friendly format.

```
private void printDepParse(Annotation document) {
        List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

        IoUtils.prln("---Dependencies---");

        for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
            // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
            SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class);
            IoUtils.prln(dependencies.toString());
        }

        IoUtils.prln("---End Dependencies---");
    }
```

Produces something like:

```
-> fed/VBD (root)
  -> Jimmy/NNP (nsubj)
  -> dog/NN (xcomp)
    -> Billy/NNP (nsubj)
    -> the/DT (det)
  -> ./. (punct)
```

Is there a simple way of producing the former, more generally accepted format?

Answer (score 1):

To get the Stanford Dependencies representation you need to use the GrammaticalStructures class. This should work:

```
     for (CoreMap sentence: sentences) {                         
            Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);             
            TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();

            GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
            GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);

            Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();

            System.out.println(tdl);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote your comment but I dont' have enough reputation.

Comment: thanks for the example. Any info on how GrammaticaStructures work_